# SQL Express database mirroring

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have 2 Microsoft SQL Express 2008 database servers (A & B), but only 1 is used at a time.

In case something happends with database server A i take the latest backup from A and restores server B from that backup, and then i run B as the active database server

In this scenario: what would be the best way to keep B up to date at all times instead of using restore from backup? Is there any smooth way to keep both databases mirrors of each other in real time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Database Mirroring and Log Shipping is not available in SQL Express editions, here is one workaround to set up log shipping ins Express edition.

[Log Shipping in SQL Express](http://blog.willbeattie.net/2009/07/log-shipping-in-sql-server-express-2008.html)

Comment: Thanks! Just skimmed through but at first glance it looks like what i'm after, i'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but maybe this will help someone else in future search for help. Your allowed to install another instance of SQL using your existing license number as long as your only using the sever as a mirror. When you bring principal back online after a failover make sure same rules apply. In other words if you have 5 databases running on principal and it goes down and you fail over one to the mirror , then when the principal comes back on line you can't have the other 4 running on primary and the mirrored db running on mirror server.